# "touch" command with a working "-f" command-line option?

Tags: touch

Older versions of the `touch` command offered a working `-f` command-line option, which could be used as follows:

```
touch -f file1 file2
```

With this command, the modification time of `file2` could be set to the same value as the modification time of `file1`.

However, recent linux versions of the `touch` command no longer honor the `-f` option ... it's now a no-op.

Can anyone point me to a version of `touch` which honors the `-f` command-line option? Source code is fine.

I know that I can write program in `C` or `perl` or `python` or some other language which will provide this functionality, but I'm hoping I can find a version of the actual `touch` command itself which offers this `-f` capability.

Thank you very much in advance.

**PS**: I don't care what language this requested version of `touch` is written in, as long as it accepts the same command-line arguments as the standard `touch` command and has a working `-f` option. If no such thing exists, I'll end up writing it, probaby in `python`, but I prefer not to "re-invent the wheel" if something like this already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `touch` uses `--reference` (`-r`) for this behaviour

```
ls -l ?
-rwx------ 1 roaima roaima 17894 Jun 23 12:32 x

touch --ref x y
ls -l y
-rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 0 Jun 23 12:32 y
```

If you really need an implementation that honours `-f` I would suggest a shell script wrapper on top of a version that supports `-r`.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! `-r/--ref` is good enough for me. I was so focused on looking for `-f` that I missed `-r/--ref` in the `touch` man page.

Comment: `touch -r` (not `--reference`) is standard, not GNU specific

Comment: Also note that `touch -r x y` will copy both the mtime and atime. Use `touch -mr x y` if you only want to set the mtime, leaving the atime alone.